# php ob_start() fix previously outputted tags

Tags: php, output-buffering

I just recently started toying with output buffering and seem to have run into a roadblock. My website utilizes a template system that loads html header/footer and the correct content template. Problem is the html headers are set in the first template loaded. So when (if) another template is loaded that contains headers (stored in a string $headers) it won't add them to the header. I have created a real sloppy way of doing this, I am looking for suggestions on to better handle this.

index.php

```
    ob_start('ob_html_headers');
```

the callback function

```
    function ob_html_headers($buffer)
    {
        global $headers;

        return str_replace('</head>', $headers.'</head>', $buffer);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd rather suggest you use a more modular templating system. Trying to fix HTML you have full control over in the first place seem like the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, interesting question. If you are trying to do what I think you are, you'd probably be better off building up the data to be sent per-section, then echoing is all out the end. You can nest `ob_start` if you don't want to go about converting all your `echo`s to $str .= quite yet.

Basically what you seem to want to do is to allow later information to affect earlier output, the best way to do that is build a structure (don't worry a few arrays of strings could suffice) that represents your page, then "render" it at the end when you know where everything needs to go.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do. I store the html headers in $headers by appending to the string then when the main template is loaded it echo's it out. Though for some reason when I ob_start() it still does not parse the $headers string with new headers if added after the main template

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why "headers" being stored in the template.

As far as I understand templating, whatever dynamic value used in the template, have to be defined in the business logic part (and most likely taken from the database).

This way you will experience no problem like this.

Comment: because I'm working with a dynamic page website instead of including every css or javascript file on every page I want to only include them as needed when their template is loaded. That's why I'm storing them for output.

Comment: This is not an excuse. You can (and should) decide what to output in the template _before_ starting any output. this is not limited to js and CSS calls. For the page title, an additional HTTP header, various design elements you will need the same. Gonna set up a distinct handler for each? Go on.